# How to replace whole numbers within a list with infinity in R programming

Tags: r, list, replace, integer

Within the object that is saved as the first element of Question3_Object, replace the whole numbers (i.e., numbers without fractions) with infinity.

1. What arithmetic function to use to identify a set of integers (whole numbers) from the object . And how do i replace it as the question asked.

````
structure(Question3_Object)
List of 3
  : num [1:7] -3 0.333 3.667 7 10.333 ...
  : num [1:21] -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
  :List of 3
  ..$ : num [1:6] 3 2.1 3.3 4 1.5 4.9
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "LOW" "MED" "LOW" "MED" ...
  ..$ : logi [1:9] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element is an integer with `x == round(x)`. and if it is, replace it with `Inf`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%%` to replace the integer values in the first element of `Question3_Object` as follows:

```
Question3_Object[[1]][Question3_Object[[1]]%%1==0] <- Inf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```r
Question3_Object[[1]][Question3_Object[[1]] %% 1 == 0] <- Inf
```

Which results in

```r
str(Question3_Object)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : num [1:7] Inf 0.333 3.667 Inf 10.333 ...
#>  $ : num [1:21] -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : num [1:6] 3 2.1 3.3 4 1.5 4.9
#>   ..$ : chr [1:6] "LOW" "MED" "LOW" "MED" ...
#>   ..$ : logi [1:9] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

---

**Data inferred from question in reproducible form**

```r
Question3_Object <- list(seq(-3, 17, 10/3), 
                         1:21 - 4,
                         list(c(3, 2.1, 3.3, 4, 1.5, 4.9),
                              c("LOW", "MED", "LOW", "MED", "LOW", "MED"),
                              1 == c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)))

str(Question3_Object)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : num [1:7] -3 0.333 3.667 7 10.333 ...
#>  $ : num [1:21] -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : num [1:6] 3 2.1 3.3 4 1.5 4.9
#>   ..$ : chr [1:6] "LOW" "MED" "LOW" "MED" ...
#>   ..$ : logi [1:9] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Amazing thank you. I have been stuck at this for so long. couldnt figure out at all